# Feeds: Do not update existing content items not working as expected

Tags: feeds

I'm trying to use feeds + tamper to do bulk updates to an entity reference field in "Employee profile" content type but retaining existing values. I'm using a CSV file and mapping a "email" and "badge" columns as source with Email (field_email) and Badges (field_badges) as targets respectively, where email is set as unique. Additionally, I have configured the processor to "Do not update existing content items". When I run the import, it finishes successfully but it says "Feeds with tamper: There are no new Employee Profile items." and nothing is being added.

If I change the processor settings to "Update existing content items", the values are being added, but the existing ones are removed.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ruben B

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straightforward way to append values to a multi-value field without custom plugins. You might need to create a custom Feeds Tamper plugin that specifically handles appending values to your entity reference field.

Comment: Thanks for the information Ram. But I have a question that might be silly for you that are experts, isn't the setting "Do not update existing content items" supposed to not impact the existing item, in this case, badges already assigned to the employee profile? I searched for information about how the processor update settings work, but there is not much.

Comment: "Do not update existing content items", items here are the employ profile records, the need for this is that when you import some items and edit them, after that the feeder will run again and you don't want it to override the changes made.
it won't go and check the referenced values and compare to add the missing ones.
That's why I told you may need to create a custom plugin or override the node processor. 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/feeds/creating-and-editing-import-feeds#processor 
or you can create a custom module to do the job without using feeds.